# AWS EC2 Ubuntu - Logging Python print statements

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, django

What is the easiest way to see "print" statements made when a Python file is executed on my AWS EC2 Ubuntu server? I have tried the aws cli, but this does not work for me.

Comment: What's executing it?

Comment: It's a django view that when accessed, runs a function in another file

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Answer (score 1):

As you said in a comment, it's part of a Django project, so if you're using the development server like `python manage.py runserver`, you should see the `print` statements in the command line you used to start it, not the AWS management CLI.

If it's running in almost any other environment (more apt to deployment), it usually has its `stdout` piped either to a logifile, or to `/dev/null`.  It depends on the exact server configuration.

In any case, it's usually better to use the Python logging facilities, which are well supported in Django.